# Uploading excel file to sharepoint list in office365

Tags: office-365

I have few complexity that I can not directly upload data from excel file to sharepoint list. Before uploading I need to do some modification to a specific column data.
So, Can we create a windows application for uploading a excel file to sharepoint list for office365.

Comment: depends on the modification, but if it concerns only one column check whether a workflow or calculated column could be a faster solution.

Comment: I need to parse data in one column as it contains html tags, its needs to be parsed before updating to list

Comment: I see and I recognize that your target is O365. So one solution might be to create an excel macro / parse the data by vba. I guess you would like to upload the data only once and after the upload has been done the excel file is superfluous?

Comment: Yes,  and currentry I am trying to do it using csom